# User authentication in tests with Django factory_boy

Tags: django, unit-testing, factory, django-authentication

When trying to unit test some part of my code, I need a user to be logged in. For reducing the number of fixtures I am using django_factory_boy User factory but the User generated is unable to authenticate.

```
from django_factory_boy.auth import UserF
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate

user = UserF()
user.set_password('password')
```

then `authenticate(username=user.username, password='password')` return `None` instead of the User. Any ideas about what is missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should call `user.save()` after `user.set_password()` because `set_password` itself does not save the user, only sets the data.

Comment: Thank you! I finally found the solution but couldn't reply to myself because of my low reputation.

Answer (score 11):

@Andrew-Magee solution works, but here the solution [describe in the doc](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference.html#factory.PostGenerationMethodCall):

```python
import factory
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
#or
#from somewhere import CustomUser as User

class UserFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):
    FACTORY_FOR = User

    username = 'UserFactory'
    email = 'test@example.com'
    password = factory.PostGenerationMethodCall('set_password', 'password')
```

Django console :

```python
>>> from tests.factories import UserFactory
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import check_password
>>> user = UserFactory()
>>> user.email
'test@example.com'
>>> check_password('password', user.password)
True

>>> user2 = UserFactory(username="SecondUserFactory", email='otheremail@example.com', password="ComplexPasswordMuchLonger!")
>>> user2.email
'otheremail@example.com'
>>> check_password('ComplexPasswordMuchLonger!', user2.password)
True
```

Comment: I also prefer this solution. It is clearly documented in [factory_boy documentation](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference.html#factory.PostGenerationMethodCall)

Answer (score 9):

Another way to do it:

```
import factory
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
from somewhere import YourUserModel

class UserF(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    FACTORY_FOR = YourUserModel
    first_name = factory.Sequence(lambda n: "First%s" % n)
    last_name = factory.Sequence(lambda n: "Last%s" % n)
    email = factory.Sequence(lambda n: "email%s@example.com" % n)
    username = factory.Sequence(lambda n: "email%s@example.com" % n)
    password = make_password("password")
    is_staff = False

>>> u = UserF.create()
>>> u.check_password("password")
True

>>> p = UserF.create(password=make_password("password2"))
>>> p.check_password("password2")
True
```